# Why can't I enable a feature on my router?

Tags: router

I have a Netgear r8000p and while trying to change my router name to an emoji, I found the following code:

[image: Picture]

The Picture shows a feature called "Super Wifi" but there is no option like that in the Transmission control settings, why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling Super Wifi only makes sense if your region is set to China. You aren't subject to the rules that Super Wifi modifies. So you cannot enable it.

Comment: yes I did set region to china but it didnt work

Comment: @Sudo I doubt that's enough. Most of the region limitations come from the region setting made before the device is shipped. If, for example, you buy a unit made for sale to the US market, it will have US regulatory restrictions that you cannot disable.